# How is Python3 list.copy() is shallow copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My understanding for shallow copy is

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a, b # ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
a[0] = 99
a, b # ([99, 2, 3], [99, 2, 3])
```

However, Python 3 document says **list.copy() Return a shallow copy of the list. Equivalent to a[:].** But this seems like a deep copy to me. Why does the documentation call it shallow copy?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.copy()
a, b # ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
a[0] = 99
a, b # ([99, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: becausefor  `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]].copy()` the `[1,2,3,4]` + `[5,6,7,8]` are still references NOT copies. so you get a new list with the same references inside - shallow copy.

Comment: Your list does not contain mutable items, so shallow and deep copy do not give not different results here.

Comment: Moreover, your first example is not shallow copying, it is _aliasing_.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye They *might* give different results. Depends on what the deep copy is doing.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye To demonstrate: Shallow copy: `a.copy()[0] is a[0]` is true. Deep copy: `[int.from_bytes([i], 'big') for i in a][0] is a[0]` is false.

Comment: @StefanPochmann That could be highly misleading for the OP at this stage. Why not use `copy.deepcopy` with the integers which returns the same interpreter int object, instead of *manufacturing* a new object with `int.from_bytes`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Because `copy.deepcopy` doesn't demonstrate my point. Of course I'm using a deep copy method that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]    
c = [a,b,25]    
d = c.copy()   # shallow, contains [a-ref,b-ref, ref of 25]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d) 
print("")

d[2] = 99 # modify only d's 3rd element

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d) 
print("")

d[1].append(15)  # change b's refs content

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d) 
print("")
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 25]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 25]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 25]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 99] # changing d[2] - its a shallow copy with 
                                 # a int thats "unique" to this list

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 15]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 15], 25] # appended to b's ref - its just a shallow copy so
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 15], 99] # changes are in both
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you so much for the detailed example. I must have confused aliasing and copying.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the first is wrong. `b` is not  a copy of `a`, it's another name for the same thing (this is aliasing). `a.copy()` is a shallow copy because it only copies the first level. Try your test again with `a = [ [1,2], 3]`.