# Subtracting elements from array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I am trying to delete elements from an array and do some calculations with this array. The thing is, I want to still keep a copy of the original array, so I made a new array and assigned it the values of the original array. The thing is, whenever I print out the length of the original and the new array, it gives me the same length, but it gives me the length of the new array. How do I make a new array with the same values as 'a', but without changing 'a'

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
b = []    
b = a    
for _ in range(2):
    m = min(b)
    b[:] = (x for x in b if x != m)

print(len(b))
print(len(a))
```

Comment: You are not copying  - you are aliasing . You give a second name to the same array (which is a list btw). try `b = a[:]` this will copy it - only works if the lists content is immutable. if your list contains other lists it will "copy" the reference to that list but not the nested lists contents - that would be a deepcopy(). search SO for python + list + deep copy

Comment: When you do `b=a`, `b` is not the empty array `b=[]` anymore, but it _becomes_ `a` (kind of) So any removal in `a` will be reflected in `b` and viceversa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: You can look at this [example with output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969887/7505395) regarding shallow copy effects with inner lists

Comment: Your numbers are conveniently ordered - to remove the lowest 2 you could simply use `b=a[2:]` - if not ordered yet and order is not important you could use `c=sorted(b)[2:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not copying - you are aliasing . You give a second name to the same array (which is a list btw). try `b = a[:]` this will copy it - only works if the lists content is immutable.

If your list contains other lists it will "copy" the reference to that list but not the nested lists contents - that would be a deepcopy().

If you want to remove the lowest 2 you could also resort to sorting and slicing (you list is already sorted so no sort needed)

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] 

b = a[2:] // slice, ignore first 2 entries which are the lowest 2 

c = sorted(a)[2:] // implicitly creates a new sorted list, ignore lowest 2

print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: My data isn't sorted at all, but thanks! I am able  to 'copy' the array now :)

Answer (score 4):

Saying `b = a` just creates a new variable that references the existing list object. To make a *copy* of a list you could use the `list()` function or list slicing:

```
b = list(a)
b = a[:]
```

That said, to create a new list from an existing one filtering out some elements you could use a list comprehension:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
m = nsmallest(2, a)
b = [x for x in a if x not in m]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between `list` and `list[:]`.
When reading, `list` is a reference to the original list, and `list[:]` shallow-copies the list.

When assigning, `list` (re)binds the name and `list[:]` slice-assigns, replacing what was previously in the list.

However, if the `list` elements are lists themselves, even `list1 = list[:]` has its problems. Consider:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0].remove(2)
>>> b 
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

This happens because each list element being copied to b is a list itself, and this copying of lists involves the same problem that occurs with the normal `list1 = list2`. The shortest way out is to explicitly copy every list element this way:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b=[[j for j in i] for i in a]   
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b[0].remove(2)
>>> b
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```